static library with C++ modules and Visual Studio Native test suite
I want to build a static library that consumes the standard library in C++ modules and exposes some of the functionality of that library. The file StaticLib.ixx below compiles just fine and produces the expected .ifc, .lib, and other files. When I create a VS Native test, (see file CppUnitTest.cpp), I added the project for StaticLib as a reference in CppUnitTest to ensure that the test unit compiles after the library project. However, the compilation of the unit test stops with errors similar to

Error C2572   'std::enable_if': redefinition of default argument: parameter 1 StaticLibTest

I thought that modules worked (in part) as headers with duplication safeguards. In any case, how can I achieve my goal?

// File: StaticLib.ixx

export module StaticLib;
import std;
namespace foo
{
export std::vector< int > bar()
{
    return std::vector< int >{1, 2, 3};
}
} // namespace foo


// File: CppUnitTest.cpp

#include "CppUnitTest.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
import StaticLib;
namespace UnitTest1
{
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD( foo )
        {

            int ans = foo::bar();

            Assert::AreEqual( 2, ans );
        }
    };
}

I have already tried different combinations of: removing the library project as reference at the test project, changing a number of project settings (e.g. build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules, C++ Language Standard, Additional BMI directories, etc.)
